# How can I build clean redirections in a controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

Right now when I want to redirect after an action in my controller I need to write :

```
function anActionAction(){
    $this->redirect("a string url like mysite/controller/action");
}
```

Is there a way to build the url a cleaner way?

For instance in the view script, if I want to get an action I use the url helper with an array like:

```
echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'snippets','action'=>'index'));
```

So is there a way to pass an array instead of a string in the redirect method?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**Redirector** Action Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector):

```
$this->_helper->redirector($action, $controller = null, $module = null, $params = null)
```

This will indirectly call the `gotoSimple()` method of this action helper.